# How do I access the Ubuntu keyring in c++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, passwords

My app needs to store a retrievable password. In OS X I use `SecKeychainFindGenericPassword` but that does not exist on Ununtu. How would I do the equivalent? (Storing the data on the drive with access permissions set to just the user is NOT acceptable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: What is the equivalent of Mac OS X Keychain Services for Linux (or Windows)?

A: For Linux, you might be interested in the Python Keychain library.  It works with Mac OSX keyring services, KDE Wallet and GNome keyring (among others):

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring#what-is-python-keyring-lib

Here is the API for KDE KWallet and Gnome Keyring, respectively:

- http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KWallet
- https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-keyring/unstable/ch01.html

You can use either/both on Ubuntu.

Here are some links to Windows equivalents:

- [Windows equivalent of OS X Keychain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442923/windows-equivalent-of-os-x-keychain)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

There are also many 3rd party libraries and components available.