# Windows equivalent of Mac Keychain Access for verifying push notification certificates

Tags: windows, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, keychain

How can a C# developer verify that Apple push notification certificates are installed correctly on their Windows machine?

Mac has the 'Keychain Access' program. What does Windows have?

Note: [Windows equivalent of OS X Keychain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442923/windows-equivalent-of-os-x-keychain) discusses passwords only

Comment: Try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In Windows certificates are stored in the [Certificate Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/view-or-manage-your-certificates).  From .Net code you use the [X509Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

> Open Certificate Manager by clicking the Start button Picture of the
>   Start button, typing certmgr.msc into the Search box, and then
>   pressing ENTER.‌  Administrator permission required If you are
>   prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the
>   password or provide confirmation